# How can I fix 'premature end of change in file'?

Tags: git, cvs, cvs2git

I'm trying to migrate an old cvs repository to git. Therefore I use cvs2git (cvs2svn 2.4.0).
There I have some files, which are corrupted: 'is not a valid ,v file. 
In order to correct these I check the rcs file format. I have detected, that everytime when the error occurs an '@', text area or an whole revision delta is missing. So I've added the missing text signs. This works very well.

But in two cases the following error occurs in pass4 of cvs2git conversion:

```
[checkout aborted:] premature end of change in 'file'
```

Has anybody an idea, for which reasons this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rcs log yourfile,v` and it might give you a better understand of what is wrong with the file than cvs2git will give you

if these files are no longer important simply remove them from CVS

you can also consider removing them from the Attic if your trying to convert the attic too.

rcs works on the most recent version first, so it may be possible to drop that diff and make the previous diff the last one (by removing the next revision)

read this [RCS Format](https://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/cvsbook/RCS-Format.html) about how to edit the ,v files